# pageBreak not working when using dynamic content with pdfmake js library

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, pdfkit, pdfmake

My attempt :

```
docDefinition.content.push(
    {
        style: 'header',
        text: String(data.designer)
    }
);
```

Works fine but I would like to go to a new page each time I add an element :

```
docDefinition.content.push(
    {
        style: 'header',
        text: String(data.designer),
        pageBreak: 'after'
    }
);
```

If I try to add a pageBreak in my node by using a loop it doesn't work and I get this error :

> Uncaught Unrecognized document structure:
>   {"alignment":"center","_margin":null}

I tried several different way. Even modifing pdfmake.js source file and commenting some lines... impossible to get it work.

Please tell me I can do this without retrieving my content array by writing it in PHP :-/ (only solution I found)

Thank you

EDIT :

> I found out where the problem was.
>
> I was retrieving a footer with a different content at each page :
>
> ```
> var docDefinition = {
>     footer: function(currentPage) {
>         return {
>             text: standnumbers[currentPage - 1],
>             alignment: 'center'
>         };
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> And when the script was doing the last page and obviously the last
>   pageBreak, my array had no more value to create the very last blank
>   page.
>
> So by doing this the pdf is finally created :
>
> ```
> var docDefinition = {
>     footer: function(currentPage) {
>         if (currentPage - 1 < standnumbers.length) {
>             return {
>                 text: standnumbers[currentPage - 1],
>                 alignment: 'center'
>             };
>         } else {
>             return {
>                 text: "END",
>                 alignment: 'center'
>             };
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: instead of pageBreak: 'after' try pageBreak: 'before'

Comment: I tried but I got the same problem. I think I will just send my array in AJAX using a POST method in an external PHP file…